# visual studio 19/22 Nunit test doesn't run by nunit adapter

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

When I run nunit tests, these tests are run by ms tests engine/adapter. I cannot run my tests in nunit adapter.
I have installed the following nugets

-NUnit 3.13.2

-Nunit3TestAdapter 3.15.0 (tried also in 4.0.0)

-Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK 16.11.0

Project .net framework 4.7.2.
Also tested in .net core 3.1, the same result.

Additional I made sure that there is not anything wrong in my project and i created new nunit test project and there is the same. Tests are run only in ms test and ms test explorer shows.
Do you have any idea why nunit test explorer cannot appear ?

Thanks in advance!

Below is auto generated nunit project by visual studio 22.

[image]

Comment: There is no "NUnit Test Explorer" It's the Visual Studio Test Explorer, which supports various framework adapters, including the NUnit adapter. In the image, it looks like your NUnit tests are found and executed... can you clarify what isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I removed NUnit adapter there is no change and everything looks like in above screen, this tests explorer don't recognize exception in tests, when nunit3 from console does. To check why my test did not run i have to run nunit3-console.exe. Back to GUI, please note that there should be button right of test to run it, test explorer should has button Run, Run All, not green arrows.

Comment: Your referenced NuGet package (NUnit, Nunit3TestAdapter, Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK) seem to be right. The 'Test Explorer' windows shows the found and executed test. Test details (e.g. exception message) can be found in the 'Summary Pane' (lower part of the 'Test Explorer' window). You can run individual tests by righ-clicking on the test and selecting run from the context menu. My 'Test Explorer' window looks just the same with NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the `NUnit 3 Test Adapter` in Visual Studio 2019
[NUnit 3 Test Adapter Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tuAU.png)

Go to `Extensions`-> `Manage Extensions`, click `Online` and search and install. You might be asked to restart Visual Studio.

AFAIK You need the packages for running the tests on the command line, say with `dotnet test` command.

Note: I can't find this extension for VS 2022. I use Resharper now to run the tests.